# Parsing json data in .txt results ValueError

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

IN `json.txt` I have this data:

```
"""{"iPod": "apple"}"""
```

This code is that parsing `json.txt`:

```
f = open("json.txt", "r")
json_data = f.read()
f.close

print json.loads(json_data)
```

It results in:

> ValueError: Extra data: line1 column2 - line2 column1(char2-24)

I want `json.txt` to remain state of now.

How do I change this code?

Comment: Why do you have the triple quotes?

Comment: unutbu is right, you json includes triple quotes which makes it invalid. You can check [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) if the format of your json is correct

Comment: Sorry.I took like it from web.

Comment: Aside: You could have said `print json.load(open("json.txt", "r"))`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why unbuntu's answer is not working is because when you read the file, it contains the `\n` char.

```
'"""{"iPod": "apple"}"""\n'
```

You have to remove it as well.

```
import json
with open("json.txt", "r") as f:
    json_data = f.read().strip('"\n')   

print json.loads(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `json_data` includes the triple quotes.
You'll need to strip them off before passing the JSON to `json.loads`:

```
with open("json.txt", "r") as f:
    json_data = f.read().strip('"')   

print json.loads(json_data)
```

Comment: Please post the result of `print(repr(json_data))`.